# Editing appears to affect maths-display

Tags: bug, mathjax

I've only noticed this since I hit 2000 rep and gained the editing privilege, but I'm not sure the two are necessarily related. It seems that after I edit a post containing equations, the equations are rendered bigger than usual. Here's a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbjAE.png

of this question: [An element of a group $G$ is not conjugate to its inverse if $\lvert G\rvert$ is odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197828/an-element-of-a-group-g-is-not-conjugate-to-its-inverse-if-lvert-g-rvert-is/197832#comment453146_197832)

You can see my answer above, which is normal, and then the answer below that I've just edited (and you can see my downvote, gasp! anonymity ruined!). In the edited answer, the $x$ is a little larger than similar $x$ in my answer above. When I re-open that page, the effect is gone - it seems to be only there immediately after editing.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? I had that same experience before I switched to Firefox.

Comment: No, I'm using Firefox, but I'll admit a rather odd setup – noscript and vimperator and so forth.

Comment: If the problem disappears after reloading the page, then I've seen that many times. In fact iirc it happens consistently for at least one browser (but I don't recall which ones). I've made it a habit of posting and immediately reloading (F5) to avoid it, so I don't really notice it any more.

Comment: In my experience (Firefox) it is not restricted to editing. MSE pages just appears to randomly render with too large math, but the surrounding non-math text is positioned for the usual size and overlapped by the overlarge math. Reloading the page sometimes helps, sometimes not. Sometimes reloading an okay page will cause the problem to _appear_.

Comment: @Henning In my experience, using Chrome, FF, IE8, Opera, on Win7 and Win XP, reloading the page (via F5) *always* corrects the problem. What version of FF and what OS are you using??

Comment: +1 Bill for reload the page.  In Safari, that gets rid of strange rendering that may exist following an edit.

Comment: @Bill, see my recent non-answer.

Answer (score 3):

*(Not an answer, but I need image embedding)*

Below is a screenshot of a case where there was no editing involved. It rendered in this way on the first pageload of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198430/14366). Reloading with F5 didn't help; nor did copying the URL manually to a new tab.

> [image]

Firefox 3.6 on Windows 7: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Firefox/3.6.15`

Comment: But if you time-travel to January 2010 (FF 3.6 release), it just might work...

Comment: I get the same problems with modern Firefox on a mac, today.